# Linking error with libjpeg

Tags: c++, libjpeg

I am compiling my own library which is linked to libjpeg.
I have this compiling on two computers but this does not work on one
of them. The error is as follows:
`Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80`
However ONLY libjpeg8 is installed:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
/usr/local/cuda-5.0/jre/lib/amd64/libjpeg.so
```

And my cmake links to the correct SO file:

```
-- Found libjpeg:
--  - Includes: /usr/include
--  - Libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
```

I honestly have no idea what is going on...
Any ideas ? Thanks in advance !

There is something stanger. If I don't link my program to any kind of jpeg libraries, my code compiles, and I can execute it and I also get the same message error. BUT, if I do a ldd on my executable, there is no trace of libjpeg. How is that possible ?

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff83bfe000)
libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4 (0x00007fa79670c000)
libopencv_contrib.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4 (0x00007fa796423000)
libopencv_core.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4 (0x00007fa795dca000)
libopencv_highgui.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4 (0x00007fa795999000)
libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 (0x00007fa7954ed000)
libopencv_ml.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.2.4 (0x00007fa79526e000)
libvitals.so.0.2 => /home/jean/Lib/libvitals.so.0.2 (0x00007fa794f7b000)
librobbie.so.0.1 => /home/jean/Lib/librobbie.so.0.1 (0x00007fa794d32000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa794a11000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa79470c000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa7944f6000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa79412d000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa793f10000)
libopencv_flann.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.2.4 (0x00007fa793ca1000)
libopencv_features2d.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4 (0x00007fa7939f8000)
libopencv_video.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so.2.4 (0x00007fa7937a1000)
libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4 (0x00007fa793522000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fa79330a000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa793102000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fa792dd4000)
libcudart.so.5.0 => /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0 (0x00007fa792b79000)
libnpp.so.5.0 => /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnpp.so.5.0 (0x00007fa78d08c000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007fa78ce66000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa78c82c000)
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa78c57a000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa78c32b000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa78c02e000)
libgtkglext-x11-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgtkglext-x11-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fa78be2a000)
libgdkglext-x11-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgdkglext-x11-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fa78bbc6000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa78b9c1000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fa78b7bc000)
libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007fa78b596000)
libxml++-2.6.so.2 => /usr/lib/libxml++-2.6.so.2 (0x00007fa78b372000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fa78b00f000)
libglibmm-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007fa78ada5000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa7969ae000)
libnvidia-tls.so.319.23 => /usr/lib/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.319.23 (0x00007fa78aba1000)
libnvidia-glcore.so.319.23 => /usr/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.319.23 (0x00007fa78864b000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fa788310000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fa7880fe000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa787ef9000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fa787cec000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fa787ae6000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fa7878c3000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007fa7875bf000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa78739f000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa787044000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fa786e30000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fa786be5000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fa7869aa000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fa7867a0000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007fa78659d000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007fa78638c000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007fa786182000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007fa785f77000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007fa785d73000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007fa785b70000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fa785967000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fa785728000)
libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007fa7854a9000)
libXmu.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXmu.so.6 (0x00007fa785290000)
libpangox-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangox-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fa785082000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fa784e60000)
libsigc-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsigc-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa784c5a000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fa784a3c000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fa78479e000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007fa784507000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007fa784304000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007fa7840f9000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fa783eda000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fa783cbf000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007fa783a28000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fa7837fe000)
libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0x00007fa783598000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fa783393000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fa78318d000)
libicule.so.48 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicule.so.48 (0x00007fa782f57000)
libicuuc.so.48 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.48 (0x00007fa782bec000)
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007fa7829e4000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007fa7827c7000)
libicudata.so.48 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.48 (0x00007fa781457000)
```

Comment: Same output ... `ldd` shows: `libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f6afef31000)`

Comment: Is it possible one of these other DSOs has an embedded libjpeg within it?  Also, what's that libjpeg in the cuda directory, and is that directory in your library path?  Do you have an LD_LIBRARY_PATH set up?

Comment: Usefull comment ! I remember that I installed a new software on my machine last night "Kingsoft Office" which installed an embedded version of libjpeg (the version 62). But I also uninstalled it last night and I made sure that only the version 8 was still present. But must have messed up my libs. Note that I also have OpenCV installed which was built long time ago with the libjpeg support. So by taking your comment in account, I just rebuilt OpenCV without the libjpeg support and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usefull comment Joe Z ! I remember that I installed a new software on my machine last night "Kingsoft Office" which installed an embedded version of libjpeg (the version 62). But I also uninstalled it last night and I made sure that only the version 8 was still present. But must have messed up my libs. Note that I also have OpenCV installed which was built long time ago with the libjpeg support. So by taking your comment in account, I just rebuilt OpenCV without the libjpeg support and everything works fine now.

Comment: Hi, how did you build OpenCV without libjpeg?